# How do I change the color of my dropdown text (Bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to bootstrap and I used a template to help me develop a nav bar for mu website, but I am confused on how to style the nav bar using a seperate CSS doc. Specifically, my toggle for the dropdown won't change color. I tried to set as many elements to color:black but they never actually effected the dropdown toggle text. The only way I could change the color was through the  tag in html (I had to use the style:"color:black;") and still it wouldn't change back to white on hover like the other elements. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong. I also wanted to add an onclick animation if anyone could help me with that as well. [This is the template I used](https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/navigation/navbar/)

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-custom">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"> <span> Artemis Server Hosting </span> </a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#basicExampleNav"
aria-controls="basicExampleNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="homepageNav">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home
           <span class="sr-only">(current)</span>
         </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="features.html">Features
         </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="pricing.html">Pricing
         </a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">idk</a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-primary" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">yet</a>
         </div>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <img src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/shopping-21/64/shopping-01-512.png" style="align:center;" height="3%" width="3%" href="cart.html">
   </div>
</nav>

   .navbar-brand {
   color: white;
  }

  .navbar-brand:hover {
  color: black;

 }

 .nav-link {
 color: black;
 }

 .nav-link:hover {
 background-color: black;
 color: white;
 border-radius: 8px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So first of all, to make your last `li` to a `cursor:pointer` you have two options:

Either put `href="#"`into the `<a>` tag, like: `<a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" ...</a>` or you use this property in the css: `a:hover { cursor: pointer }`

To color your dropdown black try this:

`.dropdown-menu > a {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
}`

Comment: Thanks, do you know if there is anyway to add an animation on click of my dropdown toggle?

Answer (score 0):

About your animation: please be a little more specific what sort of animation you want, like change the whole background color, show or hide something or whatever, but in general, if you use jQuery, you can do the following. The excample code shows an alert box

```
$(".navbar-toggler").on("click", function() {
        alert("Hello");
});
```

Please note, that this code fires if someone clicks on any navbar-toggler button on your website - if you have multiple ones, all of the will fire it! If you only want to fire it when someone click a specific dropdown toggler, you should give it an id and do `$("#your_id").` instead of `$(".navbar-toggler").`

if you don't use jQuery, the easiest would be to assign an onclick event to your button:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" [...] onclick="doSomething()">
```

and then write your JavaScript function doSomething() that does whatever you want it to do.

If you tell me what animation you want to trigger I might be able to tell you a little bit more. (Also, as a side note: you should ask only one question per post. That's how Stack Overflow works and you'll get answers faster)